# Is there something wrong with this sentence?

Tags: prepositions

I wrote in my English test:

> From 1960 both boys and girls have been allowed to study here.

Is there something wrong with that sentence?

Maybe I should have said:

> Since 1960 both boys and girls have been allowed to study here.

Comment: In an English test, "since" is probably safer, but in ordinary conversation "from" is equally acceptable and natural.

Comment: Aksu, you may not be aware that our other site [ell.se] is the best place to look for answers on English questions that a fluent speaker would find trivial. If you have a question for ELL, be sure to read their guidance on [what you can ask](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). :-)

Answer (score 1):

There's no doubt that *since* would be an acceptable substitution for *from* in the sentence, so this answer focuses on the core issue:

**Is the following sentence correct using *from*?**

> From 1960 both boys and girls have been allowed to study here.

It is both correct and natural to use the preposition *from* when you are describing a chronological starting point, such as *from 1960* in the above sentence, even if there are no subsequent words to indicate a continuum or range (such as "from 1960 *onwards*", "from 1960 *to* 1990" or "from 1960 *to now*").

The following dictionaries attest to this usage:

[**Cambridge Dictionary**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/from):

> **from** *preposition* (TIME)
>
> **A1** used to show the time when something starts
>   or the time when it was made or first existed:
>
> - *Drinks will be served from seven o'clock.*
> - *The price of petrol will rise by 5p a gallon from tomorrow.*
> - *Most of the tapestries in this room date from the 17th century.*

[**Collins Dictionary**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/from):

> 15. preposition
>       You can use **from** when you are talking about the beginning of a period of time.
>
>     - *She studied painting from 1926 and also worked as a commercial artist.*
>     - *Breakfast is available to fishermen from 6 a.m.*

[**Oxford Dictionaries**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/from):

> 2 Indicating the point in time at which a particular process, event, or activity starts.
>
> - *‘the show will run from 10 to 2’*
>
> 3.1 Indicating the date at which something was created.
>
> - *‘a document dating from the thirteenth century’*
> - *‘Customers are invited to pick up a copy of the brochure from the box office from that date.’*

In other words, it's correct to use *from* to indicate that the practice of boys and girls studying here started in 1960. For example, the context might be that until 1960 it was a boys-only school, but from 1960 both boys and girls have been allowed to study here.

---

While language schools will often teach that you should use *since* instead of *from* with the present perfect tense, I think there's a subtle difference between the two prepositions that a native speaker will exploit to convey the particular meaning they want, regardless of the tense. *From* would be more natural when the emphasis is simply on when the event/activity **started**, while *since* tends to convey the **passage of time**. Putting the phrase "from 1960" at the *start* of the sentence suggests to me that there's slightly more emphasis on the year itself, whereas if it came at the end of the sentence it loses that emphasis and *since 1960* would sound more natural.

Comment: Note: there's no example with 'from' in the Present Perfect Tense.

Comment: @user307254 nor in the present continuous or the past perfect. I don't think that matters; do you? I've provided detailed and authoritative references for my answer - perhaps you could do the same in yours? See [answer] for what EL&U is looking for. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Only the second sentence is grammatically correct.
'Since' means from the past moment to the present one.
The first sentence is incorrect because there is the preposition 'from' which means the beginning of some period. But according to the verb form (the Present Perfect Tense) this period refers to the present  time.
So, you should correct the first sentence and complete it with the words like 'up to now'.

Comment: -1 Your answer contradicts itself. Also, most fluent speakers would see no problem with **either** sentence, as it would readily be understood that "from 1960" is shorthand for "from 1960 *onwards*".

Comment: Being an English teacher I prefer proper grammar and vocabulary usage to just understanding.

Comment: Oh, an *English teacher*. You say "Only the second sentence is grammatically correct. ... The second sentence is incorrect...." How does this provide useful advice?

Comment: I did my best to explain it. For me 'for' with temporal meaning is always followed by 'to'. 'Since' includes 'from ... to now'.

Comment: I mean: 'from' is followed...

Comment: I don't think you're getting the point I'm making. Your answer says the second sentence is both *correct* **and** *incorrect*. How can it be both?

Comment: There’s a typo. Your second “second” should be “first”.

Comment: I edited the answer. Sorry for my mistake with  numerals.

Comment: They're ordinals.

Comment: You are right, ordinal (not cardinal) numerals.